# Rounding PyTables fields with round()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytables

I'm storing a bunch of data in integer format in a pytables table.
The data is factored up string stored floats, to avoid precision loss.
As an example :

```
>>> src.root.Timeseries.M1[0][5]
668000
```

If i factor down the raw number, i get the proper result:

```
>>> round(668000 / 100000.0, 2)
6.68
```

But if I factor down the int value of the PyTables field, round() doesn't work at all:

```
>>> round(src.root.Timeseries.M1[0][5] / 100000.0, 2)
6.6799999999999997
```

The PyTables field is defined by the Int64Col() datatype.

Any ideas as to what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with PyTables. PyTables gives you a NumPy array.

For example, let's use a very simple array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([668000 ])
>>> a[0]
668000
```

When you round this number you get

```
>>>round(a[0] / 100000.0, 2)
6.6799999999999997
```

This is because it has the type `numpy.float64`:

```
>>>type(round(a[0] / 100000.0, 2))
numpy.float64
```

Converting it to a Python `float`shows the shorter result:

```
>>> float(round(a[0] / 100000.0, 2))
6.68
```

So you should get something like this:

```
>>> float(round(src.root.Timeseries.M1[0][5] / 100000.0, 2))
6.68
```

The numerical values has not changed. This is all just a question how the number is represented. The standard Python `float` is represented a bit nicer the NumPy version. [Floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) are a complicated subject after all.

The way an object is represented in Python is determined by the special method `__repr__()`:

```
>>> round(a[0] / 100000.0, 2).__repr__()
'6.6799999999999997'
```

This what is used here:

```
>>> round(a[0] / 100000.0, 2)
6.6799999999999997
```

There is another special method `__str()__`:

```
>>> round(a[0] / 100000.0, 2).__str__()
'6.68'
```

It is implicitly used when you print an object:

```
>>> print(round(a[0] / 100000.0, 2))
6.68
```

​

Comment: Interesting. Especially since I had the expectation that round() would return a new number with greatly fewer decimals. In fact only 2 as used in the second parameter. Do i draw the correct conclusion when i assume round() does not work on numpy dtypes? How "This is all just a question how the number is represented" is not entirely clear to me. The reason for the confusion, is that casting to float() will, by experience, in it self not always be an exact number. So I currently feel I'm no closer to the original goal of exact representation.

Comment: It is the same number. Only how it is shown to you is different. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. Learning this, I recon using Decimal will be the way to maintain precision. The penalty of using cDecimal is about 119% extra compute time, but I can't live with the alternative.